# Use non released Rails version from Git (possibly by commit number)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, github, gemfile

I'm trying to use Passenger to host my rails app, but as noted in this [issue](https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/4277), logging is s little whacky in rails 3.2.1.  Someone has released a commit (that has been pulled into the main branch) with a fix.  How can I tell my app to use the main branch instead of a specific version of the rails gem?  Also, is there a way I can specify that commit, in case the change is later overwritten by another pull?

Something like (in my Gemfile):

```
gem 'rails', git => 'git://github.com/rails/rails.git:<commit hash>'
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The [Bundler docs note](http://gembundler.com/git.html) that you can use a specific reference like so:

```
gem 'rails', :git => 'git://github.com/rails/rails.git', :ref => '55cc16f'
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to specify a certain commit hash via the branch option:

`gem 'rails', :git => 'git://github.com/rails/rails.git', :branch => 'c67ff97ec3895db99bdb6b7cb3e8cc4e3cee0949'`

Comment: Using the :ref option is properly better but :branch works as well. Git is treating it the same.